# Return the size of lists stored in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I'm trying to convert a column in a pandas data frame into a list of items. To this end I have applied a string function to split the column variables

I first apply the following command:

```
route = df.Route.str.split('→')
route
```

and the output looks like this:

```
0                      [BLR ,  DEL]
1        [CCU ,  IXR ,  BBI ,  BLR]
                    ...            
10681                  [BLR ,  DEL]
10682    [DEL ,  GOI ,  BOM ,  COK]
Name: Route, Length: 10683, dtype: object
```

From here on, if I want to apply a length function to obtain the length of each list on this column it raises a TypeError

```
route.apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

The type of the variables is clearly a list and  when I apply a function to check the type with: `route.apply(lambda x: type(x))` it returns:

```
0        <class 'list'>
1        <class 'list'>
2        <class 'list'>
              ...
```

So why am I getting a TypeError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably `NaN`s inside your series. Try:

```py
mask = df["Route"].notna()
df.loc[mask, "Route"] = df.loc[mask, "Route"].apply(len)

print(df)
```

Alternative is to drop rows with NaN values/filling them with some default value.